# Glassfish 4, pós login no console admin abre a página: j_security_check

Tags: glassfish

*OBS: Contexto em que aconteceu o problema:
Windows 7 Professional (32 bits), Netbeans 8.2, Glassfish 4 (zip e extraído para uma pasta local).*

Galera, o Glassfish 4 starta normal, sem erros, abre o Console do Admin, mas quando me logo, abre uma pagina em branco e quando vejo o console do Netbeans tem a seguinte mensagem:

```
Grave:   An exception or error occurred in the container during the request processing
```

javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: Already connected
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.invoke(ClientRuntime.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$2.call(JerseyInvocation.java:650)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:228)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:421)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:646)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:402)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.post(JerseyInvocation.java:305)
    at org.glassfish.admingui.common.security.AdminConsoleAuthModule.validateRequest(AdminConsoleAuthModule.java:245)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.jmac.config.GFServerConfigProvider$GFServerAuthContext.validateRequest(GFServerConfigProvider.java:1175)
    at com.sun.web.security.RealmAdapter.validate(RealmAdapter.java:1654)
    at com.sun.web.security.RealmAdapter.invokeAuthenticateDelegate(RealmAdapter.java:1521)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:585)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:702)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doChainInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:678)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:246)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.portunif.PUFilter.handleRead(PUFilter.java:231)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.portunif.PUFilter.handleRead(PUFilter.java:231)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Já tentei mudar a porta do admin mas dá o mesmo erro.
Agradeço desde já qualquer ajuda que me for prestado.

Comment: Ninguém pode ajudar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RESOLVIDO: Bem amigos, quero compartilhar essa experiência que levei quase 2 semanas para resolver e que tive que descobrir na marra pois não encontrava de forma alguma uma resposta nos forums por ai. No meu Netbeans tenho o Glassfish 4 (baixei e extrai o zip mesmo e configurei o Netbeans para usar essa versão). Pois bem, o server iniciava normalmente, eu tinha que abrir a página de admin do Glassfish pela própria IDE, abria normal a página do admin para inserir o usuário e a senha, ao clicar em "Entrar" ele sempre me redirecionava para uma página em branco com o o endereço: "http://localhost:4848/j_security_check" e gerava um erro no console de saída (chamo assim) da IDE, com um erro "Grave:   An exception or error occurred in the container during the request processing javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: Already connected". Já tinha tentado de tudo e foi quando eu me lembrei de "startar" o Glassfish pelo asadmin (localizado na pasta bin do server extraído, é um .bat). Então executando o .bat, digitei: "start-domain domain1", executou com sucesso o comando. Então fui direto no navegador (não passei pela IDE), e digitei: "http://localhost:4848/login.jsf" abriu, digitei o usuário e senha e em fim abriu o console do admin do Glassfish para então eu configurar minha pool de conexão para que eu pudesse executar meus aplicativos normalmente. Então é isso. Abraço.